# Why do the same declaration in different functions result in different values?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently learning C and I am struggling on the concept of pointers.
I want to calculate the size of a char array within the respective function to limit the amount of parameters needed:

```
char palindrome(const char str[], int count);

int main() {
    char input[] = "anna";
    int size = sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]); // size = 5

    palindrome(input, size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char palindrome(const char str[], int count) {
    int size = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]); // size = 1?

    code...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If anyone can explain why the value of size differs I would really appreciate it as I think the way I use '&' and '*' is partly incorrect.  for example a pointer would refer to the address of where the variable is stored (i.e. any variable change using asterisks would globally change x's value?). I don't understand the difference of declaring a variable compared to a pointer I think is the issue.

Many thanks,
Callum

Comment: In `char palindrome(const char str[], int count)`, `str` is a pointer, not an array.  `sizeof(str)` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: And doing `sizeof(&str)` would calculate the size of the first address in the allocated heap (8)? How could I reference the array?

Comment: Nops, the size of a pointer to pointer doesn't help either, you can use `int size = strlen(str);` or better yet `size_t size = strlen(str);` from `palindrome`, but notice that `strlen` doesn't include the trailing NUL (as `sizeof` does)

Comment: `sizeof(&str)` is the size of a pointer to `char *`.  The size information of the calling code's array `input` is lost when passed as `palindrome(input, ...`. Fortunately, the needed info is passed with `size` in `palindrome(..., size)`.  `palindrome(const char str[], int count)` should use `count` as the size info.